# MVVM Frameworks for .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, caliburn.micro

What is the future of Caliburn Micro for .net core 3.0 and WPF. I get an error that it might not work in Nuget. I found nothing on Caliburn's site or on the github repository and the github entry does say that unless its a bug, ask here.

I have used Nuget and get an error of:

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Caliburn.Micro 3.2.0' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of
>   the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package
>   may not be fully compatible with your
>   project.  WpfApp1 C:\Users\Super\Source\Repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\WpfApp1.csproj  1

```
namespace CM.WPFApp1.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ShellView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ShellView : Window
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Removing InitializeComponet and it seems to work. So what are the hazards of using this if any. Should I be using the alpha V 4.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this GitHub [PR](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/pull/626), they've added support of .NET Core in Caliburn.Micro version 4, alpha releases are available via [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/feed/caliburn-micro-builds/package/nuget/Caliburn.Micro). So, for .NET Core 3.x you should use this version, `3.2.0` isn't compatible. The current version on MyGet is `4.0.135-beta`

Comment: <package id="Caliburn.Micro" version="4.0.102-alpha" targetFramework="net461" />  Should those be edited to core 3.0 in the packages for target framework? Does it matter?

Comment: It should be '<PackageReference Include="Caliburn.Micro" Version="4.0.102-alpha" />' You have to switch from 'packages.config' to  'PackageReference' format in VS. And follow the setup instructions on myget

Comment: If anyone is following along. Google "Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference".  Just a right click to get'er done in the solution explorer.

Comment: Apparently, version 4.0.102-alpha is no longer available.  I used version 4.0.62-alpha.  So far, so good.